# proto importing from parent directory does not work

Tags: c++, go, grpc, proto

Can't figure out how to do imports in proto, some help much appreciated.

The file structure:

- proto

  - api

    - item.proto
  - item.proto

I'm trying to import `proto/item.proto` into `proto/api/item.proto`

`proto/api/item.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto2";
import "item.proto"

service ItemService {

  rpc ListItems(ListItemsRequest) returns (ListItemsResponse);
}

message ListItemsRequest {
  //Empty message
}

message ListItemsResponse {

  option (grpc.gateway.protoc_gen_openapiv2.options.openapiv2_schema) = {
    json_schema: {
      required:["items"]
    }
  };

  repeated .item.Item wallets = 1;
}
```

Line for generating:

```
protoc \
    --proto_path=proto/ \
    --proto_path=third_party/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis \
    --proto_path=third_party/grpc-gateway \
    --include_source_info \
    --include_imports \
    --descriptor_set_out="$DESCRIPTOR_OUT" \
    --cpp_out="$CPP_OUT" \
    --grpc_out="$CPP_OUT" \
    --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_cpp_plugin` \
    proto/api/item.proto
```

Spits out error:

```
api/item.proto:57:12: ".item.Item" is not defined.
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you did not add a package specifier to the `proto/item.proto` file. See [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#importing_definitions), and [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#packages). If you specify a package in the imported file, you should get no errors:

```proto
syntax = "proto2";
package item;

message Item {}
```

You could also not add a package specifier to the imported file, and drop the package from the message name (in `proto/api/item.proto`):

```proto
message ListItemsResponse {
    repeated .Item wallets = 1;
}
```

As a side note, the protobuf documentation recommends that you always import files relative to the project root. I assume that this method can help in keeping the project manageable, I could not find any technical reason to recommend this. Something like this:

`proto/api/item.proto`:

```proto
syntax = "proto2";
package api.item;

import "proto/item.proto";

...
```

and generating with

```
protoc \
    --proto_path=. \
    ... \
    proto/api/item.proto
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. Main problem was specified different project names for the two files. Changed `package api_item.item` and `package item.item` to `package api.api_item and package api.item`.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy your problem was resolved